# Populating a datatable with json data using javascript in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am starting to learn javascript.

Controller file:

```
 public function index(){  

    $this->load->view('crud_view.php');

    $this->load->model('pushnotification_model');

    $data['jsonData'] = json_encode($this->pushnotification_model->search_user());

    $this->load->view('pushnotification_group_wise_view',$data);
}
```

`search_user` is a method in the model `pushnotification_model` which retrieves data from the database and returns back to the controller for json encoding.

Now in the `pushnotification_group_wise_view` I have a table like below:

```
  <div id="showUserData" data-bind="visible: records().length > 0">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>GCM REG ID</th>
            <th>EBL SKY ID</th>
        <th style="text-align:center"><button data-bind="click :$root.processAll" class="btn btn-primary">Select All</button></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:gcm_regid"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:eblSkyId"></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isProcessed"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Now I want to populate the table with the `$data` using javascript. How can I do that?**

Comment: Why do you need to do this with javascript? The view is loaded and the html is outputted. You have $data['jsonData'] in the scope of your template. Just iterate over it in the html. To do this with ajax, you should have a controller that outputted only the json data and your view should have a javascript that, via ajax request, call this controller.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `pushnotification_group_wise_view` is already have the `jsonData` you can do it using php no need to use javascript, but To do it using JavaScript you will need an endpoint to access the data result in `json` format

**in controller**

```
public function notification(){  

   $this->load->model('pushnotification_model');

   //return data as json 
   $this->output
           ->set_content_type('application/json')
           ->set_output( json_encode($this->pushnotification_model->search_user()) );
}
```

**in JS using jQuery**

```
$.getJSON( "/notification", function( data ) {

    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         //do the iteration and built the rows of  table for population here 
    });

    //and at last append it to `$('#showUserData table')`
});
```